# Problems while plotting on Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, anaconda

I'm having a problem using python matplotlib while creating a basic plot of a function, in wolfram alpha and other plotting engines the final plot seems to be so different from the one I'm creating via matplotlib.

I followed the example inside matplotlib and I just replaced the np.sin(x) function for the function I need to plot.

I'm using several functions so this is the first one I need to plot but it's not working at all.

Here's the code I'm using and the plot comparison just ahead.

```
__author__ = 'alberto'
#
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#
x = numpy.arange(-20, 20, 0.1)
y = ((3*x**2) + 12/(x**3) - 5)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Wolfram

[image: Function plotted by wolfram]

Matplotlib.

[image: Function plotted by matplotlib]

I'm using Anaconda Python(2.7.8).

Have a nice day!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make one call to plt.plot generate two disconnected curves (thus handling asymptotes) by assigning `nan` to extreme values. Mathematica handles this for you automatically; matplotlib requires you to do a little work:

```
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 1000)
y = ((3*x**2) + 12/(x**3) - 5)
mask = np.abs(y) > 100
y[mask] = np.nan
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers! Finally I got what I was doing, Thanks a lot! I was smashing my head into the keyboard X__X

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the axis labels, you can see that matplotlib is showing you a much larger viewing window than Wolfram Alpha.  Wolfram alpha is showing you roughly `-4 <= x <= 4` and `-50 <= y <= 100`, but matplotlib is showing you `-20 <= x <= 20` and y limits that are gigantic.

To get a comparable graph, set the view limits:

```
plt.xlim(-4, 4)
plt.ylim(-50, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to restrict the vertical dimension manually!
Here is a possible solution:

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.arange(-20, 20, 0.1)
y = ((3*x**2) + 12/(x**3) - 5)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(-50, 100)
plt.show()
```

Note the `plt.ylim` function!